# Why is this Array is not saving the pushed elements each time the event is triggered?

Tags: javascript

I am facing a problem: I want the array to save the x value each time the button is clicked.

So, the first time the button is clicked, the console is going to print: [48], the next time [48,48] and the third time [48,48,48]

```
<button id="me">Click me to print form E to Z</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

      const insertOptions = x=>{
    console.log(x);
  }

  const circleInsertOptions = () => {
    let myArray = [];
    let x = 48;
    myArray.push(48);
    console.log(myArray);
    return myArray;
  };

  document.getElementById('me').addEventListener('click', circleInsertOptions);

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `myArray` variable is **local** to the function. Each time the function is called, it is initialized with a new array.

If you want to define the array once then you need to define it **once** and not every time the function is called (i.e. outside the function).

Comment: ooh, yes that's true, thanks for help. I'll mark your answer as fulfilled after 12 minutes

Comment: 12 minutes have passed @KyleTech, 45 minutes ago!

Comment: sorry, I forgot it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the array outside of the function, otherwise every time you call the function, it will be reset to `[]`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  let myArray = []; // create array here

  const insertOptions = x=>{
    console.log(x);
  }

  const circleInsertOptions = () => {
    let x = 48;
    myArray.push(48);
    console.log(myArray);
    return myArray;
  };

  document.getElementById('me').addEventListener('click', circleInsertOptions);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let myArray = []; // ARRAY STORED ONCE AS GLOBAL.
  const insertOptions = x=>{
    console.log(x);
 };
const circleInsertOptions = () => {
    let x = 48;
    myArray.push(48);
    console.log(myArray);
   return myArray;
};
  document.getElementById('me').addEventListener('click', circleInsertOptions);
```